# Windows 8.1 takes Too Long for Login Form to Show

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, login, splash

One day my little brother had access to my laptop and he **hard-shutdown** on it. When I boot the laptop, sometimes the Windows 8.1 color is blue with a Rainbow Splash Screen and When I click away the splash has a forever-loading *Please Wait...*

Sometimes it shows my picture with the Green I had the Windows 8.1 set to and works like it should, but then the real issue begins when I shut my laptop lid and open it. I click the picture away and it shows just a green screen and after maybe 5-7 minutes the login screen finally shows. Is there anyway I can speed up my PC Performance to fix this issue?

My System Specs are 2.4 GHz Processor (Intel Pentium) with 6 GB of RAM. the Windows 8.1 is 64 Bit As Well. It is the Toshiba C55-A. I have already refreshed Windows once, but since I don't have recovery media, I can't do it again. My laptop didn't come with recovery media at all.

Comment: follow this and give me the boot trace: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 2):

[`This article`](http://www.registryrecycler.com/blog/2014/01/fix-windows-8-1-takes-too-long-to-start-up/) demonstrates ways to boot windows 8.1 faster.

**Switch to Local Account**

> If you have nothing to do with cloud storage, Xbox music playlists, and Windows Store, you can sign off from the live account and switch as a confined user. This will surely reduce the startup time as it was promised, less than 10 seconds.

See the instructions below.

1. Bring up `Charms bar` and click the `Settings` icon on it followed by a click on `Change PC settings`.
2. Next, go for `Accounts` on the `PC settings` interface.
3. While in `Your account` menu, the sign in address can be viewed under your username.
4. Click `Disconnect`, stated under the email ID.
5. Enter the `Current password` to verify your email account and proceed with `Next` button.
6. The next screen, titled as **`Switch to a local account`** displays a form to be filled.
7. Enter all the required fields and click `Next` button.
8. `Sign out and finish` the wizard to get it done.

**System File Checker**

> As mentioned by support staff in many threads of Microsoft Support forum, upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1 may have gone rough with certain system files. While the system boots in, it moves through Windows 8.1 legitimate files to prepare session for the user. Although, this is the least considered reason causing a slow startup, it is still harmless to scan system files for errors. For this purpose, Microsoft embeds a free tool within your operating system, called System File Checker.

Steps.

1. Go to Start screen and type `Command Prompt` to initiate a new Start search.
2. In the search results, right click `Command Prompt` and choose to **Run as administrator**.
3. In the next window, type `SFC /SCANNOW` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. System file checker will start scanning the system files.
5. Please have patience, as the scan completes detecting and repairing the damaged system files.
6. Soon as the scan completes, restart the computer.
   [image]

**Clear Boot**

> The subjected indolence might be a cause of applications and programs listing their selves in the startup list. As a result, the system loads each of these applications, soon as it boots up. Whether you want it or not, these unnecessary programs will eat up your system resources, making it slow. To realize if this is the reason of your annoyance, you can perform a clean boot and then a reboot. On the next Startup, notice the startup time. See below to learn performing a clean boot.

See the instructions bellow.

1. On `Charms bar` click Search icon and type `msconfig` in the search box.
2. Open `msconfig` from the search results and go to its `Services` tab.
3. Check the option stating `Hide all Microsoft services` and click Disable all button.
   [image]
4. Now go to the `Startup` tab and click the link saying `Open Task Manager`.
5. Select each item listed on this tab and click to *Disable* it.
   [image]
6. Close Task Manager and click *OK* button on System Configuration window.

**SSD Settings**

> It is also reported that the new Windows 8.1 is found to have issues with SSD Drives. The clash appears to occur within Windows registry, when the update changes certain registry values. These changes are unfavorable for SSDs causing them to move at a slower pace. The modified registry values are vital for optimized solid-state drives and their value data needs to be reverted. These registry entries along with their prescribed value data are described in the steps below.

Comment: I'm going to disable some start up programs in Task Manager, especially the High CPU ones

Comment: I didn't make my self clear enough.... in fact I worded it wrong. Login goes fine when I boot. It's when I close my lid and open it again, it does this

Comment: I tried System File Checker and Recieved the Error : Windows `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service`

Comment: @user2678408 To fix it do it [here](http://windowsfellow.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/how-to-fix-windows-recource-protection.html), then run again `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm trusting a site article that doesn't provide any substantiated claims, and on another article titled "tips to speed up windows 8", suggests to disable adaptative monitor brightness and run its paid registry scanner. Sigh.

Comment: @user2678408 managed to solve?

Comment: @Tiago I got a error again on sfc /scannow that files were corrupted and couldn't be fixed

Answer (score 0):

when you close the laptop lid and open it again, it can do several things depending on your power settings. Usually you want it to go stand-by or 'sleep' meaning it goes into a low-powered state that recovers almost instantly when you open it again. Another option is to 'hybernate', which saves a whole dump of your memory in a file. This is much slower to come back up, but it's safer and uses less power.

Maybe what happened is that the option was changed in control panel to hybernate (or even shutdown), or maybe the power scheme was changed.  Check under "Power Options" and check that the preferred plan is set to 'Balanced' or 'High performance', and that it hasn't been changed to hybernate.

Comment: I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Try [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/boot-time). It tells you which application is taking the longest time to boot.

> With Soluto, it’s easy to get your computer started faster. Soluto makes it simple
>   to remove unnecessary start up programs from boot, or delay apps so they start up
>   after boot. Soluto shows how much time you’ll save with each app you remove, and
>   lets you know which apps are safe to remove and whether other users removed it or
>   kept it in startup.

Comment: I have already disabled all start up apps in task manager and it still does it